# TCPListner, Winsock Check whether any client socket available to connect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, tcplistener

We have web application , it works as Socket Listner. I wanted to check before the AcceptSocket , whether there is any Client Socket available to connect to this listner. I want to display a message if there is no Client Socket to connect and cancel send/receive of data.

I am using TCPListner using ASP.net C# for the web application. The Client socket is windows VB6 application using Winsock control.

### Socketing programme, ASP.Net C#, VS2008

Thanks you for the reply ,

see below my sample code for communicate with server

clsCommunication.cs, this class file imports into .aspx page. I tried using Console.WriteLine(), but cann't shown this message.

I wanted to display alert box , so that user understands there is no connection OR display on status bar or highlight a frame/box etc.

```
public void Communicationcation()
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    string strSiteID = "SiteID";

    socket.Start();
    if (!socket.Pending())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, no connection requests have arrived");
    }
    else
    {
        client = socket.AcceptSocket();
        if (client.Connected == true)
        {
            decimal dSiteID = decimal.Parse(GetSiteSetting(ref strSiteID).ToString());
            IPEndPoint clientep = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;

            WriteLog(string.Format("Connected with {0} at port {1}",  clientep.Address,  clientep.Port));
            string strWelcome = STARTMESSAGE + "WHOAMI" + "     " + dSiteID + " " + dSiteID + FINISHMESSAGE;
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strWelcome);
            int i = client.Send(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            WriteLog(String.Format("Message sent {0} bytes!", i));

            //Get reply from the Connected cleint.
            i = client.Receive(bytes, bytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            if (i != -1)
            {
                WriteLog(string.Format(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TcpListener`'s `Pending` method, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.pending.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much @Davio it's working for me. 

and next question how to display a message if socket  client is not in pending list or not available for connect to server. I wrote communication code in class.cs file not in aspx.cs file. once again thank you.

Comment: @ShamYemul New questions should be asked in new questions.

Comment: @EJP Sorry, I got answer how to check client socket availability, but wish to show the same on status bar or message box. Not sure if thats a new question ? shall I delete this post and create new one ?

Comment: @Davio, can you help me further, It works well if remote is not available. It return false. But when remote is available then sometimes  socket. Pending () method returns false. I want a return true when remote is available.